# Should less-answered tags be worth more rep?

Tags: discussion

In Python, I've noticed that a question about getting a package installation configured right is way less likely to be answered than one about formatting a list.  The answers often tend to be very tedious, and unlikely to receive as many upvotes because these are often niche, system-specific issues.  Therefore, wouldn't it be more fair to award more rep for a good answer to such a question?

A basic weighting factor could be proportional to the ratio of the number of answers to the number of questions for a given tag?

Just curious on your thoughts.

Comment: If certain kinds of questions are niche, they won't be able to help as many people.  So it makes sense that they have fewer votes and generate less rep.

Comment: Problem with this? Rep hunters will jump from tag to tag, making tags they jump to become higher traffic until the vote worth decreases, then they'll jump ship, making the vote worth climb again, come back a while later to use that until it decreases... Not saying there's a problem with rep hunters here, but if there isn't, this would create one.

Comment: I would love this, as I tend to be active in the less popular tags (that happen to intersect with some popular ones). However, you'd have to put more work in a proposal to convince us that it is warranted. In particular you can use [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) to run your own queries and see whether there may not be perverse cases with what you are suggesting. I've sometimes had surprises when I used it to check some of my assumptions. (Note, I said I would love this but I still agree with the critiques of other folks here.)

Comment: Too arbitrary, IMO. A tag like [tag:karel] is really easy to answer, but low in yield because it is literally a beginner language.

Comment: Hmm, ya that's a good point Kendra.  I guess I just feel bad when I have a very involved question and I get one really nice answer that obviously took a lot of work, and the preson will get 10 rep from it.  Then I go to a question on indexing a string and rephunters will have 10 answers and upvote each other like crazy.

Answer (score 2):

I can totally sympathize with this. [wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wpf) answers get far fewer votes than [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) answers, and *usually* require a lot more work.

However, I find it very hard to justify a vote in a given tag being more important than any other. It would be great to find a way to "encourage" the less trafficked tags, but I don't think this is it.

Comment: It's not the first time I see this suggestion, and it was mentionned by someone that would just create more rep mongers to flood the "less popular" tags to get more point, changing the popularity of the tag, up until the tag would be 1-1 rep with the other tags, at which point the rep mongers would flood ANOTHER tag

Comment: Hmm, maybe less-trafficked tags could use a hidden rep system to add rep to an answer?  Or even in less-trafficked tags, a good answer could be nominated for additional rep, awarded by a mod?  I guess that would require too much overhead to work probably

Comment: @AdamHughes We technically already have your second suggestion in the bounty system. Granted, that currently requires someone to be altruistic enough to award the bounty.

Comment: Ya, good point.

Comment: @AdamHughes Curiously related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284190/nonlinear-reputation-rewards-automatic-bounties

Comment: Ha, do you think that's a coincidence?  One thing is for sure, people seemed to like that question a lot better than mine!  It is stated better, that's for sure.

Comment: @AdamHughes Its stated better and is less prone to abuse. It could be a coincidence, or perhaps your post got that user thinking and caused them to come up with their idea.