# Nonlinear reputation rewards (Automatic bounties?)

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bounty

I suspect this has been discussed before, but my initial search didn't show anything.

One of the things I've noticed is there's a difference between different tags/categories of average reputation of answers. This seems - at least in part - to be a design question. Upvotes - and reputation - is directly correlated to value to the maximum number of people.

My highest scoring answers aren't what I'd call my best answers. It's just I've caught a bit of low hanging fruit. I'm not overly keen on that, just generally speaking - the point of gamification is to drive behaviours in positive directions.

I'm wondering if there isn't a case for dilution/upscaling rep rewards based on some popularity metric. Partly to encourage looking at less common tags, and partly to encourage ... well, a bit more completionism I guess. Let's get unanswered questions answered, and reward people who are looking at the difficult, slower churn questions.

That's why I was thinking 'auto bounty' - would it not make sense for an upvoted question to incur a rep multiplier for each day it's unanswered? (or perhaps 'has no upvoted answers?')

Comment: I could potentially get behind this. I think that it would have to be a one-time thing awarded to the highest voted answer, say, a week after someone has gotten an upvoted answer. It also only exists if it *goes* a week without such an answer. The only issue I have is that I think you need to flesh out the details of your proposal quite a bit to make it realistically implementable.

Comment: Not a terrible idea since there are some tags that don't get much attention and even fewer votes.  But since you mentioned your own answers.... you've only been around 18 months.  The "low hanging fruit" gets quick upvotes but rarely much attention after that.  The really good answers accumulate votes over time and will eventually surpass your quick answers that got a lot of quick votes.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Unless of course your question happened to be: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074/whats-the-difference-between-string-and-string Pretty low-hanging (but no doubt commonly searched)

Comment: Some pretty nasty side-effects from such a scheme, easy to overlook.  Users will intentionally withhold an answer.  Crappy questions get attractive to answer after a while.  You'll have to flesh-out your proposal so this can't happen.  Good luck with that :)

Comment: @HansPassant I agree that such a scheme will be challenging to implement so that gaming it is hard. I sincerely doubt anyone will *withhold* an answer though, the FGITW urge is strong (and if the award is low enough, its still a better "strategy").

Comment: @HansPassant people wont hold out on answers because the fastest gun in the west problem. That might, however, happen with questions that meet whatever criteria initially. As for crappy questions, adding a  >= +3 votes and no downvotes will set a pretty high bar. Bradley's answer seems pretty solid.

Comment: ahem, pinch poke and what not @BradleyDotNET

Comment: @BradleyDotNET It has happened a few times that I skipped over questions that I *could* have answered fairly easily but that were not interesting. (All else being equal, I prefer interesting questions.) Then a few days later, the OP decided to put a bounty on the question I skipped, and then I answered. I was not actively waiting for a bounty but I benefited from not answering right away. Who knows if one would have come at all? But if an automated system dispenses bounties then why not wait? FGITW is not a factor for all questions.

Comment: @Louis Agreed, this system could delay answers on "hard enough that FGITW isn't there, but not interesting enough to answer right away". I'm not really sure how I feel about that. It seems bad, but if people are not answering *anyways* (as you didn't) then providing an incentive seems positive.

Answer (score 3):

I like the concept. As you say, it makes the game reward going for the "high fruit".

I would suggest the following details to help curtail gaming the system:

- Instead of a "rep multiplier", this is a one-time award.
- The award is restricted to *positive-score*, *open* questions only. Perhaps even a minimum score of 2 or so.
- It starts after a week of no upvoted answers, with a very low award (say 5) and grows *very* slowly.

  - As a starting point, do questions only with *no* answers. The bar for getting this special treatment should be *very* high.
- It is awarded to the highest scoring answer a week after an answer is upvoted

  - Perhaps a minimum score requirement, 2 or higher like bounties?
- There's a pretty low cap on how high the award grows. I would suggest 50 or 100 at most. This cap could be scaled to the question score to encourage answering really hard, really good questions.
- This "bounty" does *not* exempt the question from closing like a normal bounty would. Its simply to incentivize answers. The award is removed if the question is closed (potentially even after the award is given, to disincentivize answering crappy but unnoticed questions).

I'm sure there are other details that need to be added to make this workable, feel free to suggest.

In addition, it would be cool if there was a tab similar to "featured" that highlighted these questions for people looking for them.

Comment: Would the question asker nominate someone for this, or this would just automatically work on every question?

Comment: @AdamHughes I'd think it would be automatic (based on the criteria).

Comment: This kind of sounds like an auto-bounty if I understand correctly.

Comment: @AdamHughes Right... which is basically what the proposal was asking for. I just added some rules I felt were missing.

Comment: Here's a question that would fit this criteria nicely I think.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25631076/is-this-the-fastest-way-to-group-in-pandas

Clearly there should be a reward for answering this due to the number of upvotes.  I think you are right that the bounty should be fixed, but it would be cool if the more upvotes, the higher the bounty (up to some cap like say +300)

Comment: @AdamHughes After thinking about it for a bit, I've added that as a possibility to my proposal. 300 sounds a bit high though :)

Comment: Something else to consider would be the (initial?) amount of automatic bounties that are placed. I think it would probably cause some strange side effects if [16,000+ questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=score%3A3+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano+wiki%3Ano) got bounties

Comment: @CarrieKendall Excellent point. I'll think about it, and would be interested to hear your suggestion on how to handle that.

Comment: I'd perhaps think something along the lines of: Any question >7d old, with not positive voted answers would have 'community' set a bounty equal to 10x number of upvotes. And this would be auto awarded (and half would be lost) by the auto-bounty process if applicable. As this bounty expires after a week, it might also be re-created (potentially with a higher number, as more people have seen the question in the interim).

Comment: @Sobrique I hope you meant "score" not "upvotes". Also, if community creates it, who would manually award it? Wouldn't they all be auto-awards? 10x score seems a bit much as well, but those parameters could always be tweaked :) Keeping it low makes it less likely to be gamed, while still being an incentive in my opinion.

Comment: Hmm yes. Ok, score. But yes. They would all be auto awards (but bear in mind that an 'accepted' answer is auto-awarded the full amount after a week)

Comment: @Sobrique I believe thats only true if the poster is the bountier as well.

Comment: Lets take an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19423022/plackappcgibin-via-apache-and-mod-fastcgi-cgi-script-not-found

28 score ( +28 / -0 ) - no answers since October (497 views) But in a less popular tag with a niche product. I think it'd be worth a 280 rep bounty (potentially 140 if not accepted) to anyone who took the time to comprehensively answer.

Comment: And yes, the help indicates if answerer and bounty poster are the same, acceptance indicates implicit bounty award. So yes, 'community' posting it would half it, if it used the 'usual' mechanism. (Which may be undesirable, generally)

Comment: @Sobrique We can agree to disagree on the amount. Saying that every upvoter of the question would have also upvoted the answer (which is basically what a 10x bounty would do) is a bit presumptuous to me. Consider also that this system will draw more attention to the question, so answerers would get reputation from standard upvotes as well.

Comment: I'm sure there's some stats that could be extracted of ratio of question upvotes to answer upvotes that could be used.

Comment: @Sobrique I'm sure there is :). If this ever gets to the point where determining the *exact amount* is the biggest problem, its in pretty good shape!

Comment: I might suggest instead of no upvoted answers, only posts with no answers. This will really target the harder questions given their score is at least +2/-0.

Comment: @CarrieKendall Can't decide how I feel about that. What if the only answer was really bad, or a comment-answer that hadn't been flagged? The current "unanswered" status is simply no upvoted answers.

Comment: I thought about that and  get where you're coming from, but I think setting the bar incredibly high for an automatic reward system will be important. At the very least, this might be a good [focus group of questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=closed%3ano%20answers%3a0%20%20score%3a2..%20created%3a..2014-01-14) to start with.

Comment: @CarrieKendall Good point, the bar should definitely be incredibly high.

Comment: Re: initial onslaught of qualifying questions- maybe only "qualify" questions after they have some activity (only edit or up-vote)? If they're still qualified after the activity, then they can start accruing bounty.

Comment: @CarrieKendall That could work. Before implementing someone should run a SEDE query to see how many questions would qualify at any given time. That might help set the actual bar at the right mark as well.

Answer (score 2):

Automatic bounties have been discussed before but I can't find a duplicate now.

I thoroughly dislike the idea of *automatic* bounties.

Right now someone has to make the decision to put a bounty. So there is a person who is taking a stance by spending their own reputation to claim that the question on which they put the bounty is worthy of everyone else's attention. This is a *good* thing. People don't want to waste their bounty on worthless questions. Having questions with one upvote somehow gain an automated bounty will put bounties on questions that are really not worth it.

Especially in the less popular tags, you can *easily* have a clearly closeworthy question sit there for days because it does not get quickly the 5 votes necessary to close it. It can easily get a random upvote during that time. These questions should not be rewarded with automatic bounties.

Comment: That's a fair point - what would be a defensive measure? Would a threshold do it? E.g. to be eligible a question needs at least 2 upvotes?

Comment: It would take more research than I can spare right now but a really really quick search found [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17625789/eclipse-content-assist-for-amd-modules-requirejs), which clearly runs afoul of the topicness rules and yet, according to its timeline, managed to acquire **8 upvotes** (and one downvote) before being closed. It remained open about 6 months. Never got an answer. It is irritating enough when people put bounties on questions like this one. I'd rather not have an automated system do it.

Comment: No, that's a very fair point. It would be one of the downsides of doing this.

Comment: I added an extra rule in my suggestion list to try and address the closing issue. I'm sure it doesn't negate it entirely, but hopefully it helps.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Unless I'm missing something the question I found would still have gotten an automatic bounty after a few days. I see you added a provision to your answer that the bounty would not make the question unclosable but unclosability was not ever a factor for the question I found (according to what I can see in its timeline).

Comment: Ah, I thought that question may have had a (removed) bounty that caused an issue. Regardless, I'm sure there is a way to improve the ruleset.

Answer (score -4):

Alone a parallel line of thinking - I was wondering if it would be feasible to auto-scale rep rewards based on average voting.

Take the average of all >=2 score answers on >=2 score questions under every tag with more than a certain number of qualifying entries. (Maybe 50?).

Use that that number as a scaling reward for reputation awards, based on the highest number of all tags on the question. (So a popular tag + obscure tag gets the 'weighting' of the popular tag).

The idea being that you get a self perpetuating cycle of popular tags, which attract more views, which attract more votes, which attract more rep. Which is fine as far as it goes, but I think more value is added (and thus more rep is warranted) by diversity of skill and answers.

Answer (score -7):

Going on the great points of Louis and BradleyDotNET, what about a simple bounty-matching system?  IE the more upvotes a question receives, and/or the less popular its tags, the more that Stack will "match" a bounty.  This will still put the impetus on the user to front some of her rep, but will add an extra incentive.

I think that question upvotes and tag popularity are both important variables towards bounty matching, naively.